# Vertically shifted Image through RCA/Chinc connector

Tags: video

I am experiencing the oddest thing about a RCA-transmitted audio/video signal. The sound is transmitted correctly and so is the image. However the image itself is vertically shifted by roughly one third of the picture. That means the bottom third of the screen is undefined static and the upper third of the actual picture is cut off.

Some context: As I do not have a TV at the moment but want to play some Wii games, I use my trusty but quite old VCR (which works perfectly for watching VHS cassettes) which is plugged in via television cable to the TV-card of my computer. This VCR has only a mono sound input regarding the RCA signal (yellow + white) so I left the red cable coming from the Wii unplugged and connected the other (yellow and white) cables to the VCR input.

Do you have any clue what is going on? Is there any chance whatsoever I could fix this?

### EDIT

I can rule out the VCR, as I plugged the Wii directly to my TV-card (I just found out it supports chinch input) and have the exact same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem now. The Wii was configured to send out a 60 Hz signal, but my TV card could only process 50 Hz. By changing this in the Wii menu (which you could see a bit) the setup works now.